# Neo4j- binning with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

has anyone found a way to do simple binning with cypher? I have a property on the nodes and I would like to specify a (start, stop, step) and have cypher return a list of 'bins' of nodes.

I see there is a [Range](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-collection.html#functions-range) function which could be a good start, but how do I then create lists of nodes for each bin?

```
START n=node(*)
with MIN(n.t) as TMIN, MAX(n.t) as TMAX 
RETURN RANGE(TMIN, TMAX, 3600)
```

Comment: Just curious. What is "binning"?

Comment: @Pangea Automatically sorting results into various "bins". In tcb's example, he's trying to trying to stuff the results into bins sorted by the `t` parameter. So every node with a `t` value between 0-3600 would go into bin #1, 3601-7200 in bin #2, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the `case/when` syntax can do in 2.0. There's no simple way to do it in 1.9.

Comment: Even with `CASE` I don't see any way that binning could be automatic. You could hard-code several `WHEN`s in your query, but it wouldn't generate the necessary `WHEN`s for you.

Comment: Right. It would be a manual bin process. Sounds like a reasonable feature request.

Comment: it would be a fairly useful feature, and shouldn't be too hard to implement I hope, something like this would be cool "start n=node(*) with MIN(n.t) as TMIN, MAX(n.t) as TMAX, (TMAX-TMIN)/nBins as STEP return BINS(n.t, TMIN, TMAX, STEP)"